# Domestic animals for Elves and their usefulness to them

Tags: internal-consistency, fauna

At the moment I'm currently thinking of the types of animals that my fantasy Elves would use for various purposes. **I wanted to know if the ones I've come up with would be plausible and if there is anything else they could be useful for.**

## Beast of Burden

First off, I'm gonna talk about what I've come up with for their horse replacement. I'm giving them an animal to fill in the role of horses because of the terrain of Elven homeland, which consists mostly of forests, wetlands, jungles, and in general a lot of vegetation. According to all the research I've done, horses aren't exactly a fan of that type of terrain, and I don't think it's a natural habitat for wild horses. So I was gonna give them a species from the deer family. But it wouldn't just be an elk or moose, I mean like a species entirely unique in it's own right that is simply part of the deer family like elk and moose are. I still haven't decided on a name for it. Just like the case with horses, they would have been slowly domesticated over a long period of time, and specifically bred for similar purposes as horses, such as for riding on top of. There would also be several differences between this animal and other species of Deer:

This species of deer would have greater leg strength in order to be able to support a fully grown Elf on it's back as if it was a horse(I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that elk don't have good leg strength).

The antlers of this deer species wouldn't grow to be nearly as large or intricate as other members of the deer species, looking a lot more like horns, and this would be developed to prevent antlers from getting caught on various things while navigating the dense forests of the Elven homeland. I also can't recall if I read that deer antlers are sensitive, but just assume these guys would get used to still occasionally chipping or breaking their antlers.

They will also have greater stamina than the other deer species. Compared to horses however, a horse would still come out on top in terms of stamina, but only by a small margin. The deer species would also be capable of greater agility and faster speed over short distances compared to horses, in addition to being able to navigate difficult terrain such as dense forests and jungles.

**Ok now that I got that out of the way**

## Cats

Next up is cats. Felines would be another significant animal for Elves. While their most popular use would usually just be as house pets, I was thinking of giving them other uses for the elves, and potentially filling in certain roles that would normally be fulfilled by a dog. The domestic cat species that would fill these roles would also be larger than standard house cats, with the largest ones approaching medium-large sized wild cats(although they still wouldn't be quite as big as some of the largest dog species, weighing up to 90-100 pounds at the absolute largest, while there are some dog species with like twice that weight). One use I had in mind was maybe as a form of "guard" animal for nighttime when the guard dog would normally be asleep, with the cat instead taking frequent naps throughout the day, then waking up by nighttime. I know it sounds kind of stupid, it's just a concept I came up with to give them a unique role among elves. I also had the idea of having them work as hunting animals, but rather than as a companion to a hunter, they would simply be sent out to hunt by themselves and come back later with dinner. Plus, due to the wildlife in Elven homeland being more dangerous than normal, they adapted to increase chances of survival, so their skin is much stronger but more flexible(allowing them to escape a larger animal's grasp without much effort and relatively unscathed), they have enhanced senses compared to other species of cat, and are good at dealing with animals much larger than themselves. Lastly, they would also have a high level of intelligence, even for a cat.

So, I mostly want to confirm the plausibility of these domestic animals and how I proposed that the elves would use them, if it would actually be practical to have normal horses and dogs for the elves or to have species more suited to their terrain.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post so that it's clearer what question you're asking? As written it looks like you're wanting to get undirected feedback on your world. This site requires that each post asks 1 and only 1 specific answerable question.

Comment: This was a little confusing to me, too. I read this as a reality check question, especially because that second sentence. (It's not obvious.)

Comment: Sorry I got a little carried away with explaining it. I'm basically just asking if it makes sense for the elves to have these animals substitute for the roles of dogs and horses. The beast of burden is because horses wouldn't be suited for the dense vegetation of Elven homeland, and for the cat it's because the elves take a personal liking to felines as they share each other's isolationist nature and natural beaty.

Comment: Oh and the cats wouldn't completely replace dogs, like how I said that the larger cat breeds could act as a nighttime watch/guard animal while the dog that normally fills that role is asleep, because as a cat owner myself they tend to take short naps throughout the day and have a habit of going batshit crazy at 3:00 am, so I thought the elves could maybe train them to control themselves and keep an eye out for trouble.

Comment: Apparently cats tend to wake up during the night because they are genetically "programmed" to hunt at night, from what I can gather, so I just thought they could be used like a guard animal, but I'm realizing that it's probably not practical or plausible.

Comment: Hi KnightGabriel. Welcome to worldbuilding! If you haven't already, please take the [tour] and look at the [help]. Currently your questions can't be answered. First of all, there are two questions. That means one answer can be perfect for the cat question, while the other for the deer. Thus eliminating the chance at a 'best answer'. Set each in a different question. Secondly, you've already answered the questions yourself. You are holding a fictive world and have already fixed the problems you have. Unless you set the question differently, any answer would be moot. Vote to Close for now.

Comment: From our [help/dont-ask] we read, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers." So, at best, you need to split this into two questions (you need to do that anyway, asking more than one question is a reason to close, see Needs More Focus). BTW, "plausible" is always "yes" because it's your world and you set the rules, so I assume you mean, "does this meet the requirements for suspension of disbelief?"

Comment: Just to add, from extensive sci-fi reading and some fantasy reading experience (not to mention lots of classics), that suspension of disbelief relies (I should say) more on the self-consistency of the world than realism.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your question... except it is already answered. You seem to being asking us if we like your fantasy setting, and for my part I do, but this "question" doesn't follow the rules of the site. VTC. :)

Comment: Examples of historical domesticated animals:
Transport: horses, oxen, donkeys.
Meat, dairy, and hair/fibre: cattle, goats, sheep, yaks.
Hunting: dogs, cheetahs, hawks.
Pets: domestic cats, dogs, birds.
Modify to fit into elf environment. Fantasy elves are adept at making biological modifications.
Or, create new species that fill all roles (transport, milk/meat, hunter AND pet) or make lots of specialized animals. For example, in 'The Wizard of Karres', Natherby Sprites bred grik dogs who bite to kill nanite diseased people, and Nurse Beasts so they don't need to look for babysitters.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out. I'm still relatively new to this forum, I suppose it was mostly the cats I had questions about, the beast of burden I suppose I did already answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well the deer It's an entirely new creature that happens to be in the Elk and moose family. Dears were never domesticated in our world but there's nothing to say that this new branch of the dear family can't be slightly more domesticatable.

Cats.  The big problem of cats is their obedience or lack there of  This isn't so much a problem when there Small and cuddly but when they get bigger this becomes a serious problem. Training cats is not impossible though it is much more difficult than a dog. So I guess theoretically if you start young enough  You could train them to be effective guard cats but I still think that they wouldn't be as popular as dogs just because they Are much more likely to bite or to scratch their  owners.